# Special characters and json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to pull some information from a mysql database and then json encode it.  I'm running into problems with special characters. I'll pull the info from the database containing the special characters, but then when I use the PHP json_encode function, it fails to encode and returns FALSE.

I I've tried the two methods below.

In my query I have this:

```
CONVERT(item_stub.name USING utf8)
```

That didn't seem to do anything. So then I added the following to convert the data to UTF8 after the query:

```
    while($r = $db->fetch($result)){
      $r[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $r);
```

This seemed to handle non-utf8 single quotes, but I'm still having the problem with the trademark symbol.

I've also tried using the PHP htmlentities and htmlspecialchars functions, but these also fail like json_encode

Answer (score 0):

> Try adding the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to `htmlspecialchars()`. It will take care of both single and double quotes for you like so:

```
   <?php

       while($r = $db->fetch($result)){
          $r[] = array_map(
                  'utf8_encode', 
                   htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($r, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true)));
          // CODE CONTINUES... (IF ANY)...
       }
```

[QUICK-TEST THIS:](https://eval.in/662239)

```
    $r = "™™™™@†©√∫∫~ªß¥ß∂ƒåßßå∑€ƒ∑€åå€∑€∑ƒ";
    $s = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($r, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true));
    var_dump($s);
    //YIELDS:
    '&trade;&trade;&trade;&trade;@&dagger;&copy;&radic;&int;&int;~&ordf;&szlig;&yen;&szlig;&part;&fnof;&aring;&szlig;&szlig;&aring;&sum;&euro;&fnof;&sum;&euro;&aring;&aring;&euro;&sum;&euro;&sum;&fnof;' (length=196)
```

Comment: My problem is no longer quotes, but trademark symbols and accented characters. @poiz

Comment: @user2874270 Then wrap  that within `htmlentities` as the updated post indicates...*see also the appended link for testing...*

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure before use array_map function.

1. Check your PHP File Encoding and it should be UTF-8[image: File Encoding].
2. Use PHP
   header(`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`) or meta
   tag (`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;
   charset=utf-8" />`) to allow the file to handle UTF8 char.
3. Run `SET NAMES 'utf8'` sql before fetching the information.

Then use array_map and json_encode function. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
json_encode($objectSubstitutions, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```